# Bug in methods that find unmatched integers between two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to do the following function in the java code below: I am trying to generate the array of integers that do not match between 'match' array and 'original' array.

To do this I created a subarray class, a class that allows me to get the rest of unmatched elements in the two arrays (match and original), and lastly, I have a class that is called match_sequence that does the job.

My problem is there is a bug in the function that I have no idea why, for example if my input is       int[] original = {1,0}; int[] match = {1,0}; I get the residual for both original and match with [0] when it should be [], and if my inputs are {1,0,0},{1,0,0}, there is no such problem but if my inputs are both {1,0,1,0,0}, I got [0, 0] in both elements as unmatched array, when again, the result should be [] because those are perfectly matched arrays.

This is driving me insane can someone please let me know where is the bug?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
 
public class subarray
{
    // Generic method to get subarray of a non-primitive array
    // between specified indices
    public static<T> int[] subArray(int[] arr, int beg, int end) {
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, beg, end+1);
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class results {     
      private int[] array1; //array2
      private int[] array2; //array1

      public results (int[] result1, int[] result2)
      {
         array1 = result1;
         array2 = result2;
         //return results(array1,array2);
      }
      public int[] getArray1() { return array1; }
      public int[] getArray2() { return array2; }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class match_sequence {
    
    public static results match_sequence(int[] original_rest,int[] match)  {

        if(match.length <= original_rest.length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < match.length; j++) {
                //set a initial starting point plus i if we are not starting from 0
                if (original_rest[j]==match[j]) {
                    match = subarray.subArray(match,j+1,match.length-1);
                    original_rest = subarray.subArray(original_rest,j+1,original_rest.length-1);
                } else if (original_rest[j]!=match[j]) {
                    original_rest = subarray.subArray(original_rest,j,original_rest.length-1);
                    match = subarray.subArray(match,j,match.length-1);
                    if(original_rest[0]!=match[0]){
                        System.out.println("This is not an interweave of two sub elements!");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(match.length > original_rest.length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < original_rest.length; j++) {
                //set a initial starting point plus i if we are not starting from 0
                if (original_rest[j]==match[j]) {
                    match = subarray.subArray(match,j+1,match.length-1);
                    original_rest = subarray.subArray(original_rest,j+1,original_rest.length-1);
                } else if (original_rest[j]!=match[j]) {
                    original_rest = subarray.subArray(original_rest,j,original_rest.length-1);
                    match = subarray.subArray(match,j,match.length-1);
                    if(original_rest[0]!=match[0]) {
                        System.out.println("This is not an interweave of two sub elements!");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return new results(match,original_rest);
    }
    //here is the problem:  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] original = {1,0};
        int[] match = {1,0};
        //bug1: there is mismatch over here and should be resolved through debugging
        int[] rest_of_match = match_sequence(original,match).getArray1();
        System.out.println("Final match"+Arrays.toString(rest_of_match));
        int[] original_rest = match_sequence(original,match).getArray2();
        System.out.println("Final original"+Arrays.toString(original_rest));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your description of what the application is supposed to do is not very clear. Can you add some tests that show the inputs and what the expected results are?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thank you @GilbertLeBlanc, def a learning process for me, can you take a look at vszholobov's comment and help me understand why do we need to move j back? if we are just looping through the elements why is this necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside `match_sequence()` method. You slice first element of an array, but you don't move `j` index back. To do so add such line at the end of for loop:

```
j--;
```

Also `match_sequence()` contains big code duplication. If statements are redudant, you can combine them in one for loop:

```
public static results match_sequence(int[] original_rest, int[] match) {
    for(int j = 0; j < Math.min(match.length, original_rest.length); j++) {
        //set a initial starting point plus i if we are not starting from 0
        if(original_rest[j] == match[j]) {
            match = subarray.subArray(match, j + 1, match.length - 1);
            original_rest = subarray.subArray(original_rest, j + 1, original_rest.length - 1);
        } else if(original_rest[j] != match[j]) {
            original_rest = subarray.subArray(original_rest, j, original_rest.length - 1);

            match = subarray.subArray(match, j, match.length - 1);
            if(original_rest[0] != match[0]) {
                System.out.println("This is not an interweave of two sub elements!");
            }
            break;
        }
        j--;
    }

    return new results(match, original_rest);
}
```

Output:

```
Final match[]
Final original[]
```

Update:
Picture below shows why you need to move `j` back. If you don't do that, then you will skip second element of list.

[image: Why do we need to move j back]

Comment: wow thank you! Can you help me understand why do we need to move j back? I am trying to wrap my head around this part, sorry for late reply I am on the east coast

Comment: @hw21 added information about `j` index in answer

Comment: this is great, wow thank you so much, sorry I did not realize this, where did I remove the first element in the array?

Comment: @hw21 `subarray.subArray(match,j,match.length-1);` you take element from `j` to end which means you skip `j` element.  When you do this, the element that followed the `j` element itself becomes the `j` element, although before that it was `j + 1`. if you do not subtract one from `j`, then you will skip it

Comment: Thank you so much! would there be no problem if I use j-1?

Comment: Just did sorry I am new to this platform. So if I use j-1 would that work?

Comment: `j--` or `j -= 1` would work. `j - 1` won't change `j` value, only if you write `j = j - 1`. Also please read this [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: Added one more question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68809236/why-cant-i-generate-the-correct-subsegment-of-an-array

Comment: @vszholobov It is ill-advised to encourage a new user to open up additional questions over a simple homework assignment. You should have pushed back on the OP to edit his question to the point that it is clear enough to see where the problem lies before answering his or her question.